# SWTException: INvalid thread access occurs when trying to call updateButtons() from within the panel in the wizard page

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to enable/disable the `Finish` button on the `WizardDialog` depending on some field that is present in a panel residing within a `WizardPage`.

Following is the code to open the wizard dialog:

```
UserWizardDialog dialog = new UserWizardDialog(window.getShell(), new UserWizard(window.getShell()));
dialog.open();
```

Inside this `UserWizard`, there is a `WizardPage` called `CustomerWizardPage` which has a `CustomerPanel`. In this panel, I have Customer `PIN` field, depending on whose value, I have to enable/disable the `Finish` button on the `UserWizardDialog`.

In the `ItemListener` event of that field in the panel, I add the below code:

```
parent.getWizard().getContainer().updateButtons();
```

But it gives exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:463)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:355)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setEnabled(Control.java:2923)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateButtons(WizardDialog.java:1257)
at com.noi.rac.dhl.eco.util.components.CustomerPanel$4.itemStateChanged(CustomerPanel.java:304)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid thread access" happens when you modify the UI components in the Non-UI Thread.

To avoid this exception, you should modify the UI components in the UI thread. In your source code, I think you should do update your buttons in the UI Thread.

For example:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        parent.getWizard().getContainer().updateButtons();
    }
});
```

You can use syncExec() or asyncExec() based on your needs.

Hope this will help you.